# How to make Times-Roman appear instead of NimbusRomNo9L-Regu in the PDF document properties in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, pdf, times

When we generate a simple document in LaTeX using the times package (`\usepakage{times}` @ 9pt), the resultant PDF will contain NimbusRomNo9L-Regu instead of Times-Roman. (I know, this is because, LaTeX is renaming Times to Nimbus for embedding the font in PDF. Correct me if I am wrong.)

We can make Times-Roman to appear in the PDF (instead of NimbusRomNo9L-Regu) by adding some mapping in dvips configuration file (config.ps or config.pdf). How do we do this. Thus generated PS file when distilled using Adobe Distiller will show Times-Roman instead of NimbusRomNo9L-Regu.

I am searching the internet resources for a couple of days to find a suitable explanation for this. But I did not get a suitable answer. I hope somebody in this list can help me in fixing the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Sx. `times` is obsolete. You may use either `mathptmx` or the newer `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` to get roman font.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LaTeX is not *renaming* the font, but *using* NimbusRoman because that font has been set up to be used as TimesRoman. *Iff* you had purchased a proper TimesRoman font (whatever [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Times_New_Roman) is exactly) and instructed your TeX system to use that, PDFs generated from that system would display its font name.

Comment: It should be noted that Times Roman is a registered trademark of [Linotype](http://www.linotype.com/259/times.html), and Times New Roman belongs to Monotype, so it might be even illegal to call the URW version Times-Roman.

Comment: @mafp: Monotype has [bought Linotype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotype_Corporation#Consolidation_and_reorganization).

Comment: Thanks Martin for the info. Now I understand that these are two types of fonts.